# $\lim_{x\to+\infty}\frac{\int_{0}^x(\arctan(x))^2dx}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, limits, definite-integrals

Find using L'hopital's rule limit.

$$\lim_{x\to+\infty}\frac{\int_{0}^x(\arctan(x))^2dx}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$$

To do l'hopital's rule I first want to check what form it is.$\sqrt{x^2+1}$ goes to $+\infty$ when $x$ goes to $\infty$ so should $\int_{0}^x(\arctan(x))^2dx$ but how I can prove that this integral too goes to $\infty$?

Comment: Is is not necessary to check that the numerator tends to $\infty$. L'Hopital's Rule is applicable whenver the denominator tends to $\infty$.

Comment: I would not use the same symbol ($x$ in this case) for the integration variable and the upper limit of integration.

Comment: Please don't use math-only titles. They are discouraged for technical reasons - see [Guidelines for good use of MathJax in question titles](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9730/888233).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $x>1$, than $\arctan x>\frac\pi4$, and therefore\begin{align}\int_0^x\arctan t\,\mathrm dt&=\int_0^1\arctan t\,\mathrm dt+\int_1^x\arctan t\,\mathrm dt\\&>\int_0^1\arctan t\,\mathrm dt+(x-1)\frac\pi4.\end{align}And $\lim_{x\to\infty}=(x-1)\frac\pi4=\infty$.